# AppleScript to Import All in image capture not working

Tags: image, macos, applescript, capture, automator

I recently came across the following script to import all in image capture:

```
tell application "Image Capture"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Image Capture"
            click button 3 of group 2 of group 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

This doesn't work in the newest version 6.7.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me but you may need to adjust your delay value in this script.

```
tell application "Image Capture"
    activate
    delay 5
    tell application "System Events"
        click button "Import All" of group 2 of splitter group 1 of window "Image Capture" of application process "Image Capture"
    end tell
end tell
```